# The "Date modified" field in JFileChooser is not updating when we select "Refresh" option

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I was using JFileChooser for browsing the files. I have selected the view as "details".In detail mode the files are listed under four columns ie. Name, size,Item Type, Date modified. When I modify a file which the JFileChooser is currently showing and then if I right click and select the refresh option, the "Date modified" field does not get updated with the new time.

But when I go back to one folder level up and come back, the "Date modified" field will be updated with the new time.

What is the resolution to this problem??? Is it a bug???

I am using NetBeans 8.0 & its swing GUI Builder.

Please Help.

Thanks

Comment: I have been working on this for a while and the only thing that works is updateUI which resets everything. This is not what I want and I'm sure that you don't either. Currently, I'm registering the current filechooser directory with a WatchService Directory ChangeListener but when I call rescanCurrentDirectory(), it does not update the modified dates unless its a new file or the filename has changed.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: I removed the old answer because it is not correct.

**Explanation**

You mention you're using a GUI builder from NetBeans. Without seeing the code that was generated, I can only speculate at what is happening. To speculate, I would say that yes, the GUI builder from NetBeans is at fault for this - but then you might be at fault as well, depending on your perspective.

A good rule of thumb is never shalt thou ever use a GUI builder, especially in Swing. Code generation is a non-trivial task to begin with, but Swing is far more complex than most frameworks, and it makes Swing code generation that much worse. Essentially, you can look at a Swing GUI builder as a terrible entry-level developer, who will do whatever he can just to get it to work - no matter how unmaintainable or terrible the code is. The problem with this, is when something goes wrong (like it has for you), then not only do you have to know Swing to know what to look for, and you have to debug code you've never looked at before and likely will spend a great deal of time to understand, but now you the code you are trying to debug is terribly written at that. You really need to manually create your GUIs.

That being said, as I continue to speculate at what your problem is because you have no code posted, I'm guessing you tried to manipulate what the JFileChooser looks like...is this correct? If not, I suggest updating your question.

If it is the case, then that is your problem. It may seem obvious to you that the JFileChooser you are looking at in your UI is the JFileChooser that contains all the JComponents and Objects in the code. This is very wrong, unfortunately (did I mention Swing was complex?).

The JComponents you are looking at are actually part of your FileChooserUI object. If I'm not mistaken, the default FileChooserUI for any OS is javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI (it's at least the default for my local testing, and I don't think I've ever seen different for any other time I've used a JFileChooser). For your reference, here is an unmodified MetalFileChooserUI:
[image: javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI]

Now, I mention all this because it sounds like you modified how the JFileChooser looks by dragging and dropping things around. Since all the JComponents are actually housed in the FileChooserUI and not in the JFileChooser itself, what you actually did was modify the FileChooserUI. By doing this, I'm willing to bet that NetBeans created a new subclass of MetalFileChooserUI (or whatever FileChooserUI you are using). The way you might install a new UI to a JComponent would be by calling `ComponentUI#installUI`. There seems to be a flaw with this though. I haven't been able to figure out exactly how this flaw becomes a problem for the refresh, but I have my guesses. Either way, I will explain how this is a problem in the general way.

Basically, when you call installUI, it will make the UI that you are actually physically seeing look the way you told it to. However, the ComponentUI object has a reference to itself stored within the JFileChooser class and when you install the new UI, that old reference is not overridden with your new UI object. There seems to be some interaction between your JFileChooser object and the ComponentUI object when you attempt to refresh, and I believe that it is still calling the old ComponentUI reference when it needs to do any kind of update.

**Solutions**

There are two solutions here.

*Solution 1*

The first is to set the look and feel to the ComponentUI object you want before you ever create the JFileChooser using the `UIManager#put(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object)`, where the first parameter is the name of the UI you want changed (in this case it's 'FileChooserUI' and the second parameter is the string representation of the full classpath to the ComponentUI object you want to use. Before I go any further, let me say that I have not been able to get this to work properly, and my look and feel never seems to get used. What you're supposed to be able to do is the following:

```
UIManager.put("FileChooserUI", "com.my.classpath.to.MyNewFileChooserUI");
new JFileChooser().showDialog(null, "FOO");
```

and the JFileChooser will show up using the look and feel in com.my.classpath.to.MyNewFileChooserUI. The way this works, is when an JComponent is created, it goes to the UIManager and asks what look and feel it should use, and then instantiates the class it finds. You can read more about that in the JComponent documentation. As I said though, I have never been able to get that to work.

*Solution 2*

The solution I have gotten to work, is to do something a little hacky. Objectively, I don't even like this solution, and if Solution 1 worked, I would say absolutely don't do this. Since I can't figure out solution 1, I will tell you the only thing I know to work:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
MyCustomFileChooserUI fcUI = new MyCustomFileChooserUI();
try{
    Method method = JComponent.class.getDeclaredMethod("setUI", javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.class);
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(fc, fcUI);
} catch (Exception ex) { /*catch whatever you want and handle it however you want*/ }
fc.showDialog(null, "FOO");
```

What's happening here, is that I'm calling a function that is protected. This function will install your ComponentUI for you, and also override the old ComponentUI reference inside the object. So, when the JFileChooser wants to access the look and feel by reference, it will now make sure it accesses the correct look and feel Object. This is what I was speculating the issue was; it was accessing the old ComponentUI reference when trying to 'refresh' the JList inside of the look and feel that displays the files.

*Disclaimer*

There are some things I didn't talk about here, like how to override the ComponentUI object, because I think that's a little out of scope. Also, this is a long detailed answer about something that I'm speculating, because you provided very few details in your question. Another rule of thumb for you: the fewer details you provide in a question, the less people will want to help you, and the people that do will likely give you an answer you weren't looking for because they don't know what you want.

Answer (score -1):

Call the following instead of updateUI to refresh the JList in the JFileChooser:

((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel)list.getModel()).fireContentsChanged();

Comment: Thanks. Is this has to be done when **Refresh** option is selected? If so how do I know when the **Refresh** option is selected by the user.

Comment: You could set up a WatchService on the filechooser's current directory and listen for changes. If changes occur call KHANJAN's fireContentsChanged()

Comment: @KHANJAN I actually created a WatchService listener and the modified date does not change when simply modifying a file's contents using the following: javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicDirectoryModel bdm = (((javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicFileChooserUI)fileChooser.getUI()).getModel()).fireContentsChanged(); What am I doing wrong? updateUI resets everything so it is very annoying.

Comment: This is not an answer. Nowhere did the OP ever mention that he was calling updateUI(). Furthermore, this implies that the OP knows where to call updateUI() at that, and he makes no mention of ever doing such a thing. This deserves several hundred downvotes.